# How do I update LWJGL on 1.7.4 without a bin folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just downloaded Minecraft 1.7.4

I am having the sticking keys problem, where in game, I just keep running backwards and stuff and can't stop. To stop this, I need to update the LWJGL. But when I look up how to update this, I only get answers involving the bin folder in .minecraft. The newer versions of Minecraft don't contain bin folders, so I don't know what to do.

All I want to do is play Minecraft without it glitching up on me. If someone could please explain to me how to update my LWJGL on the new version, that would be wonderful. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: A quick Google shows that the LWJGL files are now located in *.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl*.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to update those so that Minecraft uses the updated version.

Comment: Where did you get this advice? LWJGL is just a OS-specific binary that comes packaged with Minecraft. Updating it wouldn't make any sense, as Minecraft ships with the version it needs. You should take a step back and ask a question with the root problem.

Comment: OPs problem is actually a common and longstanding issue.  Mojang doesn't ship the latest LWJGL which can cause issues exactly as described.  I have had the same issues in Fedora and Windows 7 with earlier versions of Minecraft and had to update LWJGL as described in OP to be able to play.  First comment seems like a good direction.

Comment: If the LWJGL files are located in `minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl` then replacing the files from this file http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.9.1/lwjgl-2.9.1.zip/download update the files.

Comment: Minecraft 1.7.4 already uses the most current version of lwjgl (version 2.9.1) therefore you should have nothing to update.

Answer (score 2):

Fix: First, rename your old lwjgl version directory. Second, copy the new lwjgl directory there, with the exact same file and subfolder structure as the old one. Next, use the Windows mklink command with the /j flag to create a directory junction, using the same name as the old lwjgl directory. This will make Minecraft think it's going to the old directory when, in fact, it's going to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

`.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl` is your new folder path for that. You can just update it from there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with updating the LWJGL libraries is that the new launcher distributed by Mojang on minecraft.net checks them, and if need be redownloads them, on every launch. In other words, as long as you use Mojang's official launcher you will always use the version of LWGJL the launcher downloads from their servers. There is no workaround for this if you wish to keep using the official launcher.