# Minecraft crashing to launcher when joining server or loading singleplayer (Minecraft 1.7.9)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried updating java, updating drivers and such and every time I press connect or load a server in Minecraft 1.7.9, it crashes back to the profile selector and launcher. Here's the error file:

http://freetexthost.com/yovtk5ycgv

It was too large to post here, so it's hosted there. If you have any idea what's wrong, let me know, all suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your minecraft is crashing somewhere in the OpenGL library, try upgrading your graphic card drivers or [update the LWJGL library for your minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152722/how-do-i-update-lwjgl-on-1-7-4-without-a-bin-folder/172454#172454)

Comment: I updated my graphics driver, worked for a few days, now this again. I don't know what's wrong this never happened before.

http://freetexthost.com/wkmp3kioc5